# might be referring to you

Tags: word, wordplay

Each digit in `12345` represents a letter. Given that:

`1`     is a letter
`12`    might be referring to you
`123`   might be referring to you
`1234`  might be referring to you
`12345` is an animal

What is the hidden word?

Comment: Would [[tag:letters]] apply here?

Comment: @bobble Interesting. But this is just like a *"With 1 I'm..., With 2 I'm..."* type of puzzle, only that here I'm giving indication that the additional letters are added to the end each time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the animal might be a:

> **HERON**

As:

> **H** is (obviously) a letter;
>  **HE** might be referring to you (if that's how you identify);
>  **HER** might be referring to you (if *that's* how you identify);
>  **HERO** might be referring to you (if you do something brave);
>  and a **HERON** is a [water bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron).